# Текстурные швы (искажения) при наложении на сферу OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, текстура

При наложении текстуры на сферу получаю искажение на полюсах (рис. 1), швы вдоль сферы особо не видны, но если убрать `GL_REPEAT` в

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

тогда и шов появляется видимый

Из-за чего это всё, я в принципе понял, проблема заключается в том, что некоторые вершины имеют координату ~0.9, а соседние с ними 0.0, из-за этого происходят большие скачки при мипмаппинге, и появляются швы/искажения

Модельки сферы импортирую при помощи библиотеки Assimp со следующими флагами

`const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals | aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace);`

P.S. Хочу использовать именно двухмерные текстуры, а не кубические карты

[image: Искажение на полюсе планеты]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете приложить картинку UV развертки? Скорее всего у вас там что-то напутано.

Comment: @Kromster, вряд ли проблема в развёртке, я пробовал множество текстур)
https://dropmefiles.com/kutlk

Comment: То что вы много текстур перепробовали, на кривость развертку никак не влияет ))) Приложите картинку развертки к вопросу пожалуйста.

Comment: @Kromster, всё, добавил, затупил, что можно прямо в вопросе было добавить картинку ещё одну..

Comment: Не текстуру, а UV развертку (типа https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQ6i6zSlGTMiI8XACSExDRD-21g-U_lRhhYw&usqp=CAU), скорее всего на у вас у полюсов неправильная.

Comment: @Kromster, добавил ещё один скриншот, гляньте, пожалуйста.
Похоже, реально меш какой-то такой себе для подобных текстур

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот смотрите, у вас у полюсов немного неправильная развертка получается:

- часть текстуры не используется (пробелы между полигонами) - отсюда швы.
- неправильная пропорция размеров полигонов - смотрите в основном на 3 последних ряда. По всей сфере высота полигонов на UV одинаковая, а верхния трия ряда "пляшут - длинный, короткий, средний, тогда как на модели, размер полигонов примерно одинаковый. Отсюда - искажения масштаба.
- второй ряд на UV почему-то диагонально раскидан и с зазорами - отсюда на модели швы и искажения.
- также, если вы делаете вид сверху, то надо круг полигонов на полюсе делать минимального размера (и проверять, что на текстуре пиксели равномерно раскрашены, чтобы не было заметно неизбежных швов в этой зоне).

---

Как быть - делать нормальную развертку. Проще всего, наверное, найти/скачать/сделать готовую модель.

Также, у правильной модели к полюсам будут не треугольники, а прямоугольники (с дегенрирующими 2 верхними точками), зато это позволит сэмплить всю текстуру.

Также, для полюсов, может быть все же проще перейти на кубические карты - в них меньше искажений/растяжек.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ))
Думаю тогда либо свою модель сделать по туториалам, либо с нормальной развёрткой скачать

Comment: С кубическими картами...я попытался создать одну, но наложилось криво, я нашёл какую-то программу cubemap.exe с SpaceEngine сайта, она разбивает на грани куба, в фотошопе можно склеить, но хз...мне кажется, проще модель нормальную сделать и всё

Comment: @ГлебТруфанов тут уж вам карты в руки, желаю удачи!